# Unity drag and drop, can an object be both "droppable" and a drop target at the same time?

Tags: unity-game-engine, drag-and-drop

I am creating a game in Unity where the board pieces can be dragged and dropped onto other board pieces. In other words, each board piece is both droppable, and can be a drop target as well.

My DragDrop script is pure vanilla, right from the Unity video about Drag and Drop. It implements these interfaces:

```
public class DragDrop : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler, IBeginDragHandler, IEndDragHandler, IDragHandler

  public void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
  {
    Debug.Log($"OnBeginDrag");
    canvasGroup.blocksRaycasts = false;
  }

  public void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
  {
    Debug.Log($"OnEndDrag");
    canvasGroup.blocksRaycasts = true;
  }

  public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
  {
    Debug.Log($"OnDrag");
  }
```

And my DropTarget script is:

```
public class DropTarget : MonoBehaviour, IDropHandler
  public void OnDrop(PointerEventData eventData)
  {
    Debug.Log($"OnDrop");
  }
```

The problem I'm having is this...

Since each game piece can be either a droppable or a drop target, that means that I have both scripts on ALL game pieces. So what's happening is, I can drag the pieces just fine, but when I drop them, **the OnDrop() event fires on Droppable piece itself, not on the object I'm dropping it on.** I guess that makes sense, but the OnDrop() event isn't firing at all on the DropTarget.

I tried to do a little "hack" by picking up on when the DragStart begins, and then trying to disable the DropTarget script on the item being dragged, such that it shouldn't fire, allowing the actual drop target to fire, but for some reason, that isn't working either.

Has anyone experienced this? Any thoughts on how to fix it?

PS - I should mention that everything I'm working with is on the UI/Canvas object. Not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: I tested with both components on each of 2 images and they worked correctly, image 1 shows OnDrag and image 2 shows OnDrop.  Can you explain what you mean by "everything I'm working with is on the UI/Canvas Object"?

Comment: Thanks hijinx. Did you put both scripts on both objects? Or did you put the drag code on one image the drop code on the other? What I mean by the canvas statement is that I'm not using any kinds of 3D Gameobjects, everything is part of the UI. I don't think it makes a difference, but just in case it does (for example, if you don't turn off raytracing as shown, then the drag won't work properly)

Comment: Yes, both components on each image.  Tested both directions and both worked.  I added `{name}` to all the debugs to be sure which component was firing on which object.  Are there other scripts that use these interfaces?

Comment: Hmm. Ok, thank you for testing it. Yes, I did the same thing as you, I added the name to each object so that I could be sure which object is firing which function. No other objects in the game use any of these interfaces. I'll start a new project and try to see if I can narrow it down.

Comment: Thanks again. Just to follow up, I created a new project, added two images just as you did, and added both scripts, and it worked as expected. I also tried it using two buttons, as my "game pieces" are actually buttons. That worked as well. So there is something else in my project causing the problem. Thanks for verifying that for me, it helps!

Comment: The only thing I can think of is an element (panel, overlay, etc) between your drag item and the drop target that has RaycastTarget set to true.  Best of luck